# uniqueFilter error in angular

Tags: php, angularjs

I have this error and I don't understand exactly why

> .angular.min.js:117 Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/unpr?p0=uniqueFilterProvider%20%3C-%20uniqueFilter
>   at Error (native).

can anyone please review my code?

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="selectedcategory" ng-options = "item.category_name for item in stockReport |
unique:'category_name'">
<option value="">בחר קטגוריה</option>
</select>    
<tr ng-repeat = "item in stockReport" ng-show = "item.category_name == selectedcategory"
 ng-init = "setTotals(item)"</>
```

Controller:

```
"use strict";
angular.module('dataSystem').controller('reportsCtrl', function ($scope, $route, $location, $http) {
  $http({method:'GET', url:'api/reports-tab/stock-report.php/'})
      .then(function(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response.data));
        $scope.stockReport = arr;   
      })    
      // This will log you the error code and trace, if there is an error.    
          .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('err', err)
          })      
          $scope.total = 0;
          $scope.setTotals = function(item){
                if (item){        
                     $scope.total += parseInt(item.quantity);
                     return $scope.total;        
                }        
            }     
    });
```

php query:

```
   $query=" SELECT  `category_name`, `refer_category_id`, `stock_id`,`product_name`,`description`,`quantity`
    from stock, stock_category  WHERE `category_id` = `refer_category_id`  group by `stock_id`  ";
```

Comment: Have you downloaded the unique library and injected it? https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to define a new filter :

```
angular.module('dataSystem').filter('unique', function() { 
    return function(collection, keyname) { 
        var output = [], 
        keys = []; 

        angular.forEach(collection, function(item) { 
            var key = item[keyname]; 
            if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1) { 
                keys.push(key); 
                output.push(item); 
            }
        }); 

        return output; 
       }; 
    });
```